# Python: List of Modules (>>> help('modules') not working)

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I wanted a list of my modules and was told:

```
>>> help('modules')
```

Would do the trick.  But I just get

> Please wait a moment while I gather a
>   list of all available modules...

For over 10 minutes before I killed it.

Anyone know what could be causing this? Or how I could otherwise see my modules? (System Ubuntu 9.10/Python 2.6.4)

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ipython

```
$ sudo apt-get install ipython
```

Then run ipython and type `import <tab>` where *<tab>* is the tab key

If you've installed the python-pygraphviz package, you can use

```
import pygraphviz
```

Comment: Awesome!  You can also see all the items within the class using this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`help("modules")` can take a long time, because it has to import each module before it can search that module's path for sub-modules. This can be a problem if any module has code outside of an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, and if that code expects user input or enters an infinite loop or hangs for any other reason.

Under the hood, `help("modules")` calls [`pkgutil.walk_packages`](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/pydoc.py#L1930), which exhibits the aforementioned "import everything" behavior. As an alternative, you can call [`iter_modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules), which does *not* import everything, with the drawback of only iterating top-level modules.

```
>>> import pkgutil
>>> print [tup[1] for tup in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
['colorama', 'xlrd', 'BeautifulSoup', 'BeautifulSoupTests', '_ctypes', ...
#snip... 
..., 'pywin', 'win32ui', 'win32uiole']
```

This will also miss out on some built-in modules, which you can get separately using `sys`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.builtin_module_names
('__builtin__', '__main__', '_ast', '_bisect', '_codecs', ...
#snip...
..., 'thread', 'time', 'xxsubtype', 'zipimport', 'zlib')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the modules you have **import**ed (directly or indirectly),

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.modules
```

`help('modules')` is about all modules that are *available* -- i.e. ones you **could* import if you wished.  It doesn't take anywhere as long for me as it does for you, but if you have installed enough extensions it could have thousands, or tens of thousands, "potential" modules to show, so it's not surprising that it might take a bit of time gathering that info.

Comment: I'm mainly trying to find a list so that I can see the name of my recently installed graphviz module which doesn't see to be found by any of the names I've tried.