# Where can I find pre-installed packages that comes with Python IDLE?

Tags: python, json, sqlite, python-idle

I'm more specifically wanting to know whether sqlite3 and json comes with python IDLE or do I have to install them separately to use them inside IDLE, If so can anyone link me to those installing procedures of sqlite3 and json on Python IDLE?

I also want to know where I can find the list of other pre-installed packages that comes with basic Python IDLE (i.e. Python 2.7.14) . I am a Beginner and it would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: List of Modules (>>> help('modules') not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550667/python-list-of-modules-helpmodules-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of your packages, from your terminal, launch python :

```
python
```

Then

```
help("modules")
```

Another solution, if you want to check if `json` or `sqlite3` are installed, start Python from your terminal :

```
python
```

Then import `sqlite3` and `json`:

```
import json
import sqlite3
```

You can check theirs version with :

```
>>> json.__version__
'2.0.9'
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

IDLE is part of the CPython standard library and is usually installed when tkinter (and turtle) are.  It provides an optional alternate interface for running your code with a particular python binary.  When you run code through IDLE, it is run by the python binary that is running IDLE.  So the same modules are available whether you run code through the terminal interface or through IDLE.  There is no separate installation.